# VBA access: how to change field value of dropdown menu on web page

Tags: html, vba

I'd like to be able to automatically change the field value from a dropdown menu on a web page
below is the source code for the select field from the web page

```
<TD CLASS="InputGridCol_InRow_1" VALIGN="center"><select name="type_1"  class=" type_input pastable_input coord_6-1">
<option class=" type_input pastable_input coord_6-1" value="">- select -</option>
<option class=" type_input pastable_input coord_6-1" value="104">test2</option>
<option class=" type_input pastable_input coord_6-1" selected="selected" value="105">test3</option>
<option class=" type_input pastable_input coord_6-1" value="119">test4</option>
</select></TD>
```

the code shows when test3 (value 105) is selected from the menu.

I' ve tried the vba code below without success:

```
Fdname = "type_input pastable_input coord_6-1"
ieDoc.getElementsByClassName(Fdname).Item(105).Selected = True
```

any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select the options by class name and loop the returned collection. When "test3" is found do whatever it is you want to do.

```
Dim currentOption As Object
For Each currentOption In ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("type_input pastable_input coord_6-1")
   If InStr(currentOption.innerText, "test3") > 0 Then
       currentOption.Selected = True
   End If
Next currentOption
```